# Redux calls dispach function but it does not change the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am writing `LoadingComponent` which should return a `Spinner` when some data is loading and when it is done it should return `this.props.children`.

I am getting the data at `componentWillMount`:

```
class LoadingComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.userActions.onUserAuthChange();
        this.props.currencyActions.getCurrencies();
    }
}
```

I check if one of user or currencies is loading and if so return `Spinner`:

```
 render() {
    const {loadingUser, loadingCurrencies} = this.props;

    if (loadingCurrencies || loadingUser) {
        return (
            <Spinner/>
        )
    }
    return (
        this.props.children
    )
}
```

Here is where I connect the `state` to `props`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
  loadingUser: state.loading.loadingUser,
  loadingCurrencies: state.loading.loadingCurrencies,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  userActions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch),
  currencyActions: bindActionCreators(currencyActions, dispatch),
});

const ConnectedLoading = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(LoadingComponent);

export default withRouter(ConnectedLoading);
```

And the `loadingReducer`:

```
const loadingReducer = (state = initialState.loading, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.LOADING:
        return {...state, isLoading: action.loading};
    case actionTypes.LOADING_USER:
        return {...state, loadingUser: action.loadingUser};
    case actionTypes.LOADING_CURRENCIES:
        return {...state, loadingCurrencies: action.loadingCurrencies};
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

The thing is that `loadingUser` and `loadingCurrencies` are always false. This is `getCurrencies` function which dispatches with true when the data starts downloading and after that dispatches with false:

```
export const getCurrencies = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        dispatch(loadingCurrencies(true));
        const currencies = await get();
        dispatch(loadCurrencies(currencies.rates));
        dispatch(loadingCurrencies(false));
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

I am using the LoadingComponent at App.js:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <LoadingComponent>
            <div className='App'>
                <Route path='/:lang' render={props =>
                    languages.hasOwnProperty(props.match.params.lang) ?
                        <Navbar {...props}/> :
                        <Redirect to={`/${defaultLanguage}`}/>}
                />
                <Layout/>
            </div>
        </LoadingComponent>
    )
}
```

This is the reducer function which listens for `loadCurrencies(currencies.rates)`:

```
const currencyReducer = (state = initialState.currency, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENCIES:
        return {...state, currencies: action.currencies};
    case actionTypes.CHANGE_CURRENCY:
        return {...state, current: action.current};
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

During debugging noticed that at the `LoadingComponent` the Redux Dev Tool is not active and it starts to be active at `LoadingComponent`'s children. Actually, when I set breakpoint at the reducer the state changes... And after Redux Dev Tool starts to be active I can observe that the loading states actually had been changed false -> true -> false. I would highly appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: can you post the reducer that listens to `loadCurrencies(currencies.rates)`?

Comment: Where is the part where you connect your Loading component to the store through `connect()` ?

Comment: What happens when your empty catch is caught? You should remove that whole try/catch wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding `redux-logger` to your store: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger. This will help identify the sequence of events firing.

My initial thought is that you might have a race condition between `loadCurrencies` and `loadingCurrencies` returning. If `loadCurrencies` is a promise, then `loadingCurrencies` should dispatch in a `then` block to indicate the promise has returned.

IMO having bool arg methods is a code smell, and since the loading state is tied to the actual load method, it makes sense to have loading be a part of the same reducer. A pattern I typically follow is:

action

```
export const getCurrencies = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestCurrencies()) // loading: true
    return api.getCurrencies()
      .then(currencies => dispatch(receiveCurrencies(currencies)))
  }
}

export const requestCurrencies = () => ({
  type: REQUEST_CURRENCIES,
  loadingCurrencies: true
})

export const receiveCurrencies = currencies => ({
  type: RECEIVE_CURRENCIES,
  currencies,
  loadingCurrencies: false
})
```